# Get field names of view from within module

Tags: entities, views

After using `views_get_view($view_name)` how do I get the names of the fields?  The list of field names (arranged correctly) is going to be pushed onto an array following which will be all the results.  I can see in the return value from `views_get_view()` the `field` array, but how do I get them as they would be displayed in a table, that is, correct capitalization, spaces instead of underscores, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an array of fields in the display object:

```
$view->display['YOURDISPLAYNAME']->display_options['fields']
```

for example if you want to retrieve list of field names of the view arbitrary display, you'd need to do something like this:

```
function get_views_field_names($view_name, $display = 'default') {
   $view = views_get_view($view_name);
   $result = array();
   foreach($view->display[$display]->display_options['fields'] as $field){
       $result[] = $field->label;
   }
   return $result;
}
```

and somewhere in the code

```
$fields = get_views_field_names('YOURVIEWNAME', 'YOURDISPLAYNAME');
```

Comment: Huge help, but I had to make a couple changes.  I added `if !isset($view->display[$display]->display_options['fields'])){$display = 'default';}` in case the display is supplied but uses the defaults.  Also, `$field` is an array not an object so I used brackets.